# python - abstract method in normal class

Tags: python, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I was reading official python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod).

In the mentioned link, the second line states that:

> Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is ABCMeta or
>   is derived from it.

But, I was successfully able to define the below given class.

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self):
        return self.a

a = A()
a.f()
```

So, the code above worked fine.
And also, I was able to create a subclass

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__() 

b = B()
b.f()
```

Without overriding the abstract method defined above.

So, basically does this mean that if my base class's `metaclass` is not `ABCMeta`(or derived from it), the class does not behave like an abstract class even though I have an abstract method in it?

That means, the documentation needs more clarity?

Or, is this behaviour useful somehow and I'm missing the point.

Comment: How were you expecting it to work? I think the documentation is pretty clear. Also, I'd say, here is not the place to discuss documentation issues.

Comment: I expect `Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is ABCMeta or is derived from it.` to be enforced?

Comment: @harman786 Problem is that the only way in Python to enforce something like that is with a metaclass. It's a Catch-22.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So, basically does this mean that if my base class's metaclass is not
>   ABCMeta(or derived from it), the class does not behave like an
>   abstract class even though I have an abstract method in it?

Correct.

All `abstractmethod` does is mark the method with `__isabstractmethod__ = True`.  `ABCMeta` does all the real work. [Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/abc.py#L9) is the code for `abstractmethod`:

```
def abstractmethod(funcobj):
    """A decorator indicating abstract methods.
    Requires that the metaclass is ABCMeta or derived from it.  A
    class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta cannot be
    instantiated unless all of its abstract methods are overridden.
    The abstract methods can be called using any of the normal
    'super' call mechanisms.
    Usage:
        class C(metaclass=ABCMeta):
            @abstractmethod
            def my_abstract_method(self, ...):
                ...
    """
        funcobj.__isabstractmethod__ = True
        return funcobj
```